# iPhone/iPad - Facebook api for universal app

Tags: iphone, facebook, ipad, universal-binary

I know that facebook api works on iphone.
I want to port my iphone app which has facebook api to Universal app so that it works on iPad as well.
How can I achieve it? Is there any facebook api for universal apps or do I've to use two api's one for iphone and one for ipad. If I've to use them separately, how can I compile and build my application?

Please suggest me some way for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try: http://www.getsharekit.com/